# jQuery $(document).ready fires on one computer and not others

Tags: jquery

I have the following jQuery code (simplified for question purposes):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    alert("Test");
});
```

Its inside a the  of a .NET master page.  This code fires on some of our computers but not on others.  All users have the same version of IE and I also have tested this on Firefox with the same results.  All browsers have scripting enabled and stuff like that, at This point I don't know what else could be causing this issue.  I am using jQuery version 1.3.2.  Of course my real code is more interesting than what I posted, but if I cant get an alert to fire, then what use is the rest  :)...

Any help is welcomed.

Thanks

Comment: How are you loading jQuery? How are you loading your script with the ready handler in it?

Comment: Do some computers have javascript disabled? Is this a corporate network we're talking about here?

Comment: have you debugged in firebug? are you pulling in the jquery library from google or loading it locally? if the former, are you connected to the internet on your computers where it doesn't work?

Comment: Sixten, Im loading jQuery right above my call to it:  this is how Im loading it:

<script src="http://localhost/SimpleTools/Scripts/jquery-1.3.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

this script with the ready handler is inside a script block as follows:

<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        alert("Test");
    });
</script>

Karim:  Al computers have java script enabled.  It is a corp network...

Jason:  I have debuged in firebug and code does not break there.  I am loading the lib localy.

Comment: By the way, if I place a simple javascript call outside of the $(document).ready block it does fire.

Comment: Please try something like setTimeOut("alert($)", 1000). I need to know that jQuery is loaded or not. Or you give me the complete rendered html and required JavaScript files.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    alert("test");
});
```

If it doesn't work try adding a console.log(jQuery) for firefox or similar just before and see what that gives you when it fails.

Answer (score 0):

If you are calling a localhost file are you sure all computers have access to the localhost server? Try changing it to:

```
<script type="text/Javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

And see if that works